# Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy one column from a workbook to another workbook. This is my code and the error I am getting.

> (Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range)

```
Sub CopyColumn()
Dim sourceColumn As Range, targetColumn As Range

Set sourceColumn = Workbooks("source").Worksheets("a").Columns("H")
Set targetColumn = Workbooks("copyto").Worksheet("HCM_FBL_Person_Template_Sample_").Columns("A")

sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn
End Sub
```

Comment: Unless `a` and `HCM_FBL_Person_Template_Sample_` are variables containing either the indexes or names of sheets, they should be in quotes, e.g.: ...`Worksheet("HCM_FBL_Person_Template_Sample_")`

Comment: Tried that, still not working :/, same error

Comment: You need to confirm that each workbook and sheet name is spelled exactly as what's in quotes in your code. And, of course, as noted by Paul, the workbooks must be open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to open the files first, using exact file names (including their absolute path), and exact sheet names including any spaces

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyColumn()
    Const FILE1     As String = "C:\TestFile1.xlsx"
    Const FILE2     As String = "C:\TestFile2.xlsx"
    Const SHEET1    As String = "Sheet2"
    Const SHEET2    As String = "Sheet1"
    Const COL1      As String = "A"
    Const COL2      As String = "D"

    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, wb As Workbook, wbInfo As String
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim sourceColumn As Range, targetColumn As Range

    If Dir(FILE1) > vbNullString And Dir(FILE2) > vbNullString Then
        For Each wb In Workbooks
            wbInfo = "\" & wb.Name
            If InStr(1, FILE1, wbInfo, vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then Set wb1 = wb
            If InStr(1, FILE2, wbInfo, vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then Set wb2 = wb
        Next
        If wb1 Is Nothing Then Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(FILE1)
        If wb2 Is Nothing Then Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(FILE2)
        If Not wb1 Is Nothing And Not wb2 Is Nothing Then
            For Each ws In wb1.Worksheets
                If ws.Name = SHEET1 Then Set ws1 = ws
            Next
            For Each ws In wb2.Worksheets
                If ws.Name = SHEET2 Then Set ws2 = ws
            Next
            If Not ws1 Is Nothing And Not ws2 Is Nothing Then
                Set sourceColumn = wb1.Worksheets(SHEET1).UsedRange.Columns(COL1)
                Set targetColumn = wb2.Worksheets(SHEET2).UsedRange.Columns(COL2)
                sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

---

This also checks if the files are already open or not, and if sheet names exists in each file

Comment: It now just crashes excel completely

Comment: This method says that the file is already open and then it crashes

Comment: So I know have the code running on a third workbook and it is not crashing. it now opens the files, but the columns are not being transfered

Comment: I made a change to the last part and verified that it works

Comment: Worked! Thank you! You were a major help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will solve your problem-

```
Sub sbCopyRangeToAnotherSheet()

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Z1").Copy

     Range("A1:Z1").Select
     Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
     ActiveSheet.Paste

     Application.CutCopyMode = False

     End Sub
```

ALternatively if you dont want to specify fixed range you can declare a Range object as use End(xlLeft) to select all range from A1-allleftColumns-

I hope it will help you.

Comment: My issue is that its not copying from one sheet to another but rather one workbook to another workbook